# Defining a closeEvent function with parameters in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

How do I put parameters in closeEvent function and then whenever the window is closed, the closeEvent function is called with a particular argument that I want to pass to it?

Comment: You can't. Events are internally "created" by Qt and delivered to the target objects directly. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @musicamante Do you have a discord where I could text you?

Comment: Please try to improve your question and explain what you want to do. Please keep in mind that StackOverflow is not a help desk, questions and answers are for *public* utility. What you're asking might be helpful to others, exactly as it happened when other asked or answered something before and you found their posts helpful to you.